# Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute

Tags: c#, wcf

When I send this DTO via WCF to my server side I get this error:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:objects. The InnerException message was 'Enum
>   value '3' is invalid for type 'LPFLogger' and cannot be serialized.
>   Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with
>   EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute
>   attribute.'. Please see InnerException for more details.

My DTOs has no DataContract attribute I don't use them at all. Its not needed by default.

Why is value 3 a problem? Because my enum has only 0,1,2 ?

```
public class MyObjectDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public LPFProcessor Processor { get; set; }
        public LPFAccess Access { get; set; }
        public LPFLogger Logger { get; set; }
    }

public enum LPFLogger
    {
        None = 0,
        EventLogger,
        TempLogger
    }
```

Comment: making enum LPFLogger : int did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below code to check if enum already exits at your server end

```
 private static LPFLogger GetLPFLogger(int value)
    {

        var lstEnum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LPFLogger)).Cast<int>().ToList();

        if (lstEnum.Any(s => s == value))
            return (LPFLogger)value;

        return LPFLogger.None;
    }
```